# How to get the "Gene-ius" achievement in Pixel People?

Tags: pixel-people

There is an achievement (that can be seen from the police station achievements wall on page 3) that says "Get a quick surprise at the gene pool".  I've been playing for weeks and still have yet to encounter this.  Any ideas on what triggers this?  I'm also already at 118/150 for types of jobs found, but I'm not sure if there's a "gene pool" structure I still haven't unlocked or there's something else I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, when you unlock the geneticist (which I did at about 135/150) you also unlock the "Gene Pool" building.  Mine is still under construction, but I can update more after it is built if things are not completely obvious from there.

And incase you are wondering how to make a geneticist:

> scientist + doctor = geneticist